# Navigation menu Hover effect and Active effect (Custom CSS on Elementor/Wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I'm an absolute begginer when it comes to code (that's why I'm using elementor to build my site)

I'm trying to style the nav menu with custom css since the provided solutions look a bit ugly.

So far i have managed to create and "underline" hover effect that I'm happy with using CSS Hero.

I would like the underline to be permanent when I'm on the selected page.

So far I have managed to get an underline on the active menu but the hover animation keeps displaying on top.

I'm aware that the code is a mess, and that this is not the proper way to do this but It's the ebst I can do.

```
.elementor-6618 .elementor-element.elementor-element-faa673a .elementor-nav-menu--main .elementor-item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.elementor-6618 .elementor-element.elementor-element-faa673a .elementor-nav-menu--main .elementor-item:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 51%;
  right: 51%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: ##212121;
  height: 1px;
  transition-property: left, right;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.elementor-6618 .elementor-element.elementor-element-faa673a .elementor-nav-menu--main .elementor-item:hover:before,
.elementor-6618 .elementor-element.elementor-element-faa673a .elementor-nav-menu--main .elementor-item:focus:before,
.elementor-6618 .elementor-element.elementor-element-faa673a .elementor-nav-menu--main .elementor-item:active:before {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.elementor-6618 .elementor-element.elementor-element-faa673a .elementor-nav-menu--main .elementor-item.elementor-item-active{
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: #212121;}
```